# Enabling XRDP for remote on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3 (HVM), SSD Volume Type

Tags: opensuse, suse

All these test activity I am carrying out on my AWS instance for my test purposes.

I am bit of new Linux playground and I needed your guys expertise for configuring it. I am trying to install XRDP for Remote access on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3 (HVM), SSD Volume Type on AWS & stuck up. Actually I am trying to configure XRDP on the AWS Linux instance.

I followed this tutorial but no success : https://www.suse.com/documentation/s...igure_rdp.html'

Previously : All these options were pretty simple & straight forward on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4 (HVM), SSD Volume Type. Can anybody please through some light on this !! how to configure Linux instance so that I can continue with the installation of SAP B1 9.3.

Current Issue : Getting the logging screen & after entering the credentials then everything is blank, I cannot do anything on the screen. No UI nothing, Even I tried setting the display to 16-bit or 24-bit only but no success.

So let me know your thoughts or suggest some document which explains how to configure Linux 12 for XRDP.

Comment: How does your .xsession file look like?

Comment: sorry since i am a newbie in linux can you please let me know where I can find that file !!! I tried searching for the path in my root/user-name/ but folder is empty also tried to search via hidden files root/*user-name/ but again the folder is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been solved !!!

Below are the steps I performed & it will be helpful for them who stumble upon the same issue.

```
# zypper update ( to update SUSE Linux Ent. Server)
# zypper install -t pattern gnome-basic
# zypper install xrdp
```

**Enable VNC Remote Login**

```
# Open yast, Select "Network Services", Select first entry "Remote Administration with VNC"
# Enable service
```

Configure Window Manager to use Gnome
Edit file /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager
Change entry DEFAULT_WM="" to DEFAULT_WM="gnome

**Startup the RDP service and make it start automatically after Reboot**

```
# service xrdp start
# chkconfig --set xrdp on
# systemctl start xrdp
# systemctl enable xrdp
```

Above are the steps which I performed to get the activate & use RDP session through my windows, If in-case anybody have any question let me know I will be happy to assist you.

Regards,

Rahul Jain